# Python rounding grades

Tags: python, rounding-error

Trying to round student grades to nearest multiple of five. If grade is two or less closer to the round then that grade gets used. What is wrong with my current code

```
Grade = input(23)
Round_grade = (((grade/5)+1)*5);
New_grade = (Round_grade - grade)
If (New_grade - grade) <=2;
Print (New_grade);
Else (Print (grade))
```

Expecting new grade of 25 to be printed

Comment: that's not Python...

Comment: Your casing is wrong, for starters. `if` and `else` are keywords and should always be lowercase. `print` is a function and should also be lowercase.